# Mac - TFS - Eclipse Error : unable to instantiate class "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.views.TeamExplorerView

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs

**Requirement:** Install TFS in eclipse

**Methods Followed:**
Installed software from the following URL http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs.

Once the software is installed, Team Explorer opened with following steps.
Clicked on Window -> Show Item ->Team Foundation Server - > Team Explorer

**Issue :**
Following error message is shown when i tried to open Team Explorer

*Plug-in "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui" was unable to instantiate class "com.microsoft.tfs.client.common.ui.views.TeamExplorerView".*

**Softwares Used:**

Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers

Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0),
Build id: 20191212-1212

Java version "13.0.1"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing),

OS : MacOS Mojave

*Am I missing something? Is it happening to everyone? Does java version matter?*

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using? Did you check eclipse version requirements against TFS plugin version you are using?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Answer (score 4):

This linked helped me to fix the same issue.
https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/285

Download 14.135.0 from - https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases

- Open Eclipse.
- On the Help menu, click Install New Software.
- The Install dialog box appears.
- Choose the Add button.
- The Add Site dialog box appears.
- For the name, enter “TFS plug-in for Eclipse”.
- Under the Locations Click Archive and browse through the TFSEclipsePlugin-UpdateSiteArchive-14.135.0.zip file.
- Install TFS packages.
- Restart

Answer (score 0):

According to the reviews on the [Eclipse Marketplace ***Team Explorer Everywhere*** entry](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/team-explorer-everywhere#comments), the plug-in **no longer works with current Eclipse versions**.

Unfortunately, the current *Team Explorer Everywhere* version seems to be from 2018. It might be that the plug-in uses internal classes from the Eclipse platform, which would explain why it does not work even though it can be installed. See the error log for details.